# Trigger a +1 & -1 scroll with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, lazy-loading

I use the following function to trigger a +1 and -1 scroll using jQuery in order to make images show up when using lazyload in combination with isotope or else the images wouldn't show up when filtering.

```
function forceLoad(){
    $.scrollTo("+=1px");
    $.scrollTo("-=1px");
};
```

It works in FF and Chrome browsers but not in Safari (testing with version 6).

Any ideas on what I could try to produce the same behaviour using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code:

```
function forceLoad(){
    $(window).trigger("scroll");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [LazyLoad plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), I think you can force all of the images to load by triggering the `appear` event:

```
$('img').filter(function() {
  return $(this).offset().top < $(window).height();
}).trigger('appear');
```

Comment: This would trigger all images? I need the images to be loaded only when in viewport.

Comment: Filter all of the images whose vertical position is less than the height of the viewport.

Comment: If you visit http://gablabelle.com/ with chrome everything is perfect when using the filtering menu and then if you try with safari you will see that if you do not scroll the images don't appear.